# Static block on home page in Magento

Tags: xml, magento

I am trying to add a static block to the home page of a Magento site using the layout XML file.

I can see how to add and remove block inside a reference, but I am struggling to see how to add it for a specific page, i.e. the home page.

```
<block type="cms/block" name="home-page-block">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home-page-block</block_id></action>
</block>
```

How would I wrap this code in the `page.xml` file for it to be only used on the homepage?
Or is there a better way? Should the home page be a new template?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In any layout file used by your theme add the following.

```
<cms_index_index>
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="cms/block" name="home-page-block">
      <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home-page-block</block_id></action>
    </block>
  </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

`cms_index_index` is specific to the home page.

Comment: Thanks, I have got it to work by adding a reference tag around the block and giving the reference a name attribute of content.

Does this mean that there has to be a call in the .phtml template to a "reference" and anything with that name is rendered?

Comment: I forgot about the reference part! Somewhere in each page .phtml template there will be a `getChildHtml('content')` in place. That is why it works.

Comment: Thanks again, that answers my original question, however I don't seem to be able to add getChildHtml('home_flash') in the .phtml file and use <reference name="home_flash"> in the XML file. Any ideas why?

Comment: Because `reference` only refers to an existing block, it does not create a new one. In the above example you already created a block called `home-page-block` and could explicitly show it with `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('home-page-block') ?>`

Comment: @snh_nl That is complex enough to be it's own question, so please start a new one.