# Create a new Block in Magento

Tags: php, xml, layout, magento, block

I asked this question yesterday [Static block on home page in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366177), which answered my question about hooking a cms/block to an existing block (content, in that example).

But now I would like to know how to create my own block.

I have this in my .phtml template:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('home_flash') ?>
```

And this in my cms.xml file

```
<reference name="home_flash">
  <block type="cms/block" name="home-page-flash" before="content">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home-page-flash</block_id></action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

But this is not working.

I have also tried to create my own block type, (by copying the breadcrumbs declaration) in the page.xml file:

```
<block type="page/html_home_block" name="home_block" as="home_block" template="page/template/home_block.phtml"/>
```

That file exists but isn't being rendered.

However when I reference the block like this:

```
<block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="home_block" as="home_block" template="page/template/home_block.phtml"/>
```

It renders my home block template, but the original cms/block is not attached to it.

Hope all the different cases show what is happening and highlight the gap in my knowledge well enough for someone to answer, do I have to "register" my new "home_block" type somewhere?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're trying to accomplish, which makes understanding the questions difficult. Could you explain what the end result you're trying to achieve is, as well as be more specific about things? (i.e. "my .phtml template": which phtml template?)

Comment: @Alan Storm, Thanks for the comment, I know the question was long and I tried to sum it up in a one line question at the end! @clockworkgeek has answered my question and it turns out I was missing the point about the MVC bit of Magento!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different blocks available that you can use without creating your own. In this case I think `core/text_list` would be suitable because it doesn't require a template and can have as many child blocks within it as you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0"><!-- All layout files start with this -->
    <cms_index_index><!-- Index directive is the same as "home" page -->
        <reference name="root"><!-- For more blocks that can be referenced see "default" directive -->
            <block type="core/text_list" name="home_flash">
                <block type="cms/block" name="home-page-flash">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home-page-flash</block_id></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>

    <!-- More directives might go here -->

</layout>
```

Other useful block types worth knowing are `core/text` and `core/template` which correspond to `Mage_Core_Block_Text` and `Mage_Core_Block_Template` respectively. They get used the most.
Your home made block type of `page/html_home_block` didn't have any PHP class with a matching name, and if you were genuinely creating your own you wouldn't be able to use the `page` prefix since Magento already does.

To create a block you only need a `<block>` tag in the layout file.
To create a block type you need to write a PHP class, give it a namespace and declare it as part of a module.
To add to an existing block is the time when you use a `<reference>` tag.

There are many fine articles at [Magento Knowledge Base](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base) including some on [Theming & Design](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/theming-design/).

Comment: Thanks for the full and complete answer, I have struggled to find documentation on the Knowledge Base that wasn't either super simple or way over my head. I will look into the existing blocks now, and might even poke around the other side of the MVC bit.