# Display custom block at Magento Home page

Tags: php, magento

I saw this answer [Static block on home page in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366177/static-block-on-home-page-in-magento) but cant make it work.

Im just trying to add a custom block in my home page. These are the things I've done:

1- Add this to my layout file.

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
       <block type="aitshopassist/assistant" name="aitshopassist_assistant" template="aitshopassist/assistant.phtml">
           <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>shop_assistant_block</block_id>
           </action>
       </block>
     </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

2- Added this to the 2columns-right.phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('shop_assistant_block') ?>
```

Also, the block is shown correctly in catalog_category_view.

What am I missing?

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="aitshopassist/assistant" name="aitshopassist_assistant" template="aitshopassist/assistant.phtml" before="category.products" />
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

I tried this in the cms_index_index but didnt work..

Comment: The `getChildHtml` method is going to look at the `name` value, which is `aitshopassist_assistant`, not `shop_assistant_block`.  How is this showing correctly in `catalog_category_view`?  Can you paste the layout update that you used to pop it in there?

Comment: I edit the question, there is the catalog code for the layout. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <block type="cms/block" name="aitshopassist_assistant" before="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>shop_assistant_block</block_id></action>
  </block>
```

set it in xml file for calling block

Answer (score 0):

Just echo following code in your home phtml file:

```
$this->getLayout() ->getBlockSingleton('aitshopassist/assistant')->setTemplate('aitshopassist/assistant.phtml')->toHtml();
```